# How to merge multiple python source file into single one?

Tags: python

I need to merge multiple source py files into single one.
So that I could upload it to an online python environment which doesn't allow creating nested directories.

The source py files are nested in different directories, but not too many or too deep.

I was thinking to achieve this by using some comments, a merger exe reads those comments and concats the content of those files.

Is there a more reliable & official way to do this?